# Get postcode and zone name from shipping zones in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm developing a plugin that adds a shipping method that accepts rules for  calculating shipping cost, some of those rules are the post codes and the zone. How can i access the data that is configured in the image below?
[image: Woocommerce Shipping Zones Configuration]

I know i can make a query to the database at woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations but i was wondering if there is a better way using the woocommerce api.

Comment: It depends on the shipping zone ID

Comment: So how can i get the shipping zone ID where my shipping method is? After that i can do get_zone_by and get the shipping zone, after that i can go to the $data array and get the locations to get the data that im looking for.

Comment: May be [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423109/woocommerce-get-shipping-zone-name-from-the-shipping-method-id/47425463#47425463) could be useful

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you need.

```
<?php
 $shipping_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($shipping_zones); 
 echo '</pre>';
?>
```